# How to add the Author on my RSS Feed

Tags: rss, feed, feedburner

just done on my feed burner, I noticed however, that author is not being labeled in the RSS feed: http://feeds.feedburner.com/BiotechStart . How should I able to do that? any idea please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually is working, though FeedBurner doesn't include it in the HTML page. When I add it to a feed reader, the authors show up. I'm not completely familiar with FeedBurner, perhaps there's a settings for that?

Comment: I already explored, I did not see any option to display the author of my wordpress blog on the feedburner. Or maybe I just missed it.

Comment: Well, chances are nobody will revisit the HTML page. So I think you can rest happy knowing that in the end, it's actually still working behind the scenes.

Comment: ok, thanks buddy :) happy valentines (linsanity) day!